# Find a homotopy

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, surfaces

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56366/) from [mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) it is asserted that the following two surfaces are homotopic. My basic question is - is this true?

[image]

It's clear to me that the two surfaces are homeomorphic, but homotopic seems more difficult to see, since the homotopy must disentangle the apparently knotted structure in the box. I don't actually doubt it, I just don't see it easily.

If they are homotopic, is it possible to exhibit the homotopy explicitly? If so, it might be possible to generate an animation illustrating the homotopy.

Comment: The upper end of the left bar slides down the middle bar.  You have all the freedom you need to detangle in the resulting configuration. (Both ends of the left bar are at the bottom.) Afterwards you can go up again if you want to. The interior of the box is the exterior of the left connected tori.

Comment: Please forget my comment about the interior and exterior. You can identify both surfaces as they are.

Comment: All homeomorphic spaces are trivially homotopic. What you seem to be thinking of is a concept like *ambient homotopy*.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes, I am certainly curious if these are homotopic as subsets of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Tobias I don't quite see what you're saying but, thank you. I hadn't considered the possibility that the interior and exterior flip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step of the homotopy will simply straighten out the left most tube: let the strand that loops around the middle tube pass back leftward through that middle tube, so that the leftmost tube then just has a trefoil knot tied in it; and then let the trefoil knot pass through itself to straighten out the left most tube so that it is completely vertical just like the other two tubes.

The second step of the homotopy is a (non-smooth) isotopy: simply round out the angled edges of the right picture, and then flatten it out somewhat; you get the left picture.

Comment: Thank you. When you say, "let the strand that loops around the middle tube pass back leftward through that middle tube" - is that not exactly what we're trying to avoid? It is possible, though, that either I've misstated the question slightly or I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: Under a homotopy $h \bigm| S \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$, although the initial restriction of the homotopy $h \bigm| S \times 0$ might be an embedding, as might be the terminal restriction $h \bigm| S \times 1$, the intermediate restrictions $h \bigm| S \times t$ are not required to be embeddings. That's precisely the difference between homotopy and isotopy: under an isotopy, *every* restriction $h \bigm| S \times t$ is required to be an embedding, for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! So you're saying, for example, that the trefoil knot is homotopic to a torus, but not isotopic. Makes sense, now that I think about it, but that's not how I've used the term in the past. I would say that this addresses my question, then. I am wondering, though, whether the figures are isotopic.

Comment: What you say about the trefoil knot is mostly correct, except I would word it to say that the trefoil (regarded as an embedded circle) is homotopic to the un-knot but not isotopic. At this point, though, whether the figures are isotopic has become a different question.